# How to convert text to uppercase (or lowercase) in-place in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How to convert text to uppercase (or lowercase) in-place in Excel / Office 365?

[This page](https://www.exceldemy.com/change-lowercase-to-uppercase-in-excel-without-formula/) suggests to use the Change Case button, but there's no such button in my copy of Excel, and it does not even appear in the list of available buttons when customizing the Ribbon.

EDIT: The Change Case button appears to be in Word, not Excel. However, the question stays: is there a similar button/option in Excel?

Comment: I don't believe Excel ever had a 'Change case' (I even verified in custom ribbon, all commands). Your screenshot implies the workaround: copy into Word, change case, then I guess it has step four missing: copy back into Excel

Comment: Ah, I see. You're right. I am editing the post. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Perhaps you could explore using an add-in, either creating your own or an existing one.

Answer (score 12):

One way to do this is through VBA. You don't even have to write a macro, just select all the cells you want to convert, hit Alt-F11 followed by Control-G, and type:

```
For Each myCell In Selection.Cells : myCell.Value = UCase(myCell.Value) : Next
```

This will convert all the selected cells to uppercase (note that if the cell has a formula, it will change it to its current value!)

Comment: Excel functions exist to do this, you don't need VBA. But kudos for suggesting an alternative solution that's not a workaround.

Comment: @spikey_richie, I know, but the question was "in place", so you'd have to enter the formula somewhere else and then copy/paste values on top of the original. I thought this was easier :-)

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't scale very well to large numbers of cells, but an *in-place* version of @spikey_richie's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1804432/1091192) is:

- Start with your existing text:

[image]

- Edit the expression in the formula bar to surround the existing text with `=upper("` and `")`, but **don't** press <kbd>enter</kbd>:

[image]

- Now press <kbd>F9</kbd> to *evaluate* the expression, which will replace the formula in the cell with the calculated value:

[image]

- And *then* press <kbd>enter</kbd> to accept the value:

[image]

Note if there are special characters like double-quotes in the string you'll need to escape those as well, so this approach has limited usefulness, but it can be handy for a quick bodge.

The <kbd>F9</kbd> key is also useful for other expressions - I frequently use `=TODAY()` + <kbd>F9</kbd> to enter today's literal date into a cell so I don't have to look at my calendar :-).

Comment: "I frequently use =TODAY() + F9 to enter today's literal date into a cell so I don't have to look at my calendar :-)." Just use Ctrl + .

Comment: @Arsenal - I'm always looking for extra keyboard shortcuts, but I'm not quite sure I get what you mean. I just tried "ctrl +" and it seems to do the same as F9, but maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Go to an empty cell and use Ctrl + . (that is the period key not the period to end the sentence) it will insert the current date.

Comment: Ah, got you. It's an unfortunate coincidence that [ctrl] + [+] *also* evaluates an expression :-). Having said that [ctrl] + [ . ] (dot) didn't work here for the date - the documentation at https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-b5663451-10b0-40ab-9e71-6b0ce5768138 says it's [ctrl] + [ ; ] (semicolon) which *does* work for me...

Comment: Oh then maybe they use different shortcuts for the German Excel, or our company uses a different mapping, but I've known [ctrl] + [.] to work for more than 6 years and I changed companies in between, so I think it's more of a German / English thing...

Answer (score 4):

Use Excel's `=Upper()` and `=Lower()` functions.

Uppercase

[image]

Lowercase

[image]

There's also `=Proper()`, which outputs like this:

[image]

You can then copy values of the correctly formatted cell, over the top of the original incorrect text.

Comment: This doesn't change the text in existing cells in place.

Comment: @pts was that an explicit requirement in the OP's question?

Comment: Both the question title and text contain *in-place*, and this is how I interpret it.

Comment: @pts you're right, I missed that bit. I've updated my answer to include additional detail which would meet this criterion.

Answer (score 3):

The page you have linked to gives several different methods for converting case in Excel.  The button in the screenshot you have pasted is actually in MS Word, not MS Excel.  The guide is suggesting you copy the text from Excel to a table in Word, change case using the button on the Word ribbon bar, then copy-n-paste it back into Excel.

Comment: This is a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: You are correct. @gregg pointed that out, too. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Automate tab to create and run [Office scripts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel) if you meet the [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/overview/excel#requirements). These scripts are like macros but they are written in TypeScript and are saved to your Office account so you can reuse them in other workbooks.

Here is an example of a script that changes the case of selected cells in-place on a cell-by-cell basis.

```typescript
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    
    const selectedRange = selectedSheet.getSelectedRange();
    const rowCount = selectedRange.getRowCount();
    const colCount = selectedRange.getColumnCount();

    for (let c = 0; c < colCount; c++) {
        for (let r = 0; r < rowCount; r++) {

            const cell = selectedRange.getCell(r, c);
            const text = cell.getText();
            
            if (text.length === 0) {
                continue;
            }

            const isLower = text[0] === text[0].toLowerCase();

            if (isLower) {
                cell.setValue(text.toUpperCase());
            } else {
                cell.setValue(text.toLowerCase());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In-place in Excel? Not really, there is practically non-existent support for regex.

Luckily, copying data from Excel puts it in tab-separated format so you could use a competent text editor to achieve the results:

1. Copy your data from Excel
   [image]
2. Paste into Notepad++ or anything with robust regex support like regex101.com
   [image]
3. Initiate regex find+replace

   - Find: `[a-z]` or you can use `.` instead to account for non-English characters
   - Replace: `\U$0`
   - Alternatively, you could select all the text and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
4. Replace All
   [image]
5. Copy+Paste back into Excel
   [image]

Comment: Or if formatting & formulae aren't an issue, then Save-As-CSV  then change case in a text editor, re-open the file in Excel - cuts out the potentially messy cut-n-paste.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way of using VBA functions.
You can also invoke VBA functions from the Name Box. Don't need equal sign, may use arguments, references may be also in R1C1 style (local), punctuation also local. Function must return reference. For example:

```
Function UP(rng As Range) As Range
      Dim c As Range
      For Each c In rng
            c.FormulaLocal = UCase(c.FormulaLocal)
      Next c
      Set UP = ActiveCell
End Function
```

In the Name Box:     UP(D3:H5),     UP((A3;B5;C2))      (use local separators, press Enter)

```
Function UPS() As Range
   Dim c As Range
   For Each c In Selection
      c.FormulaLocal = UCase(c.FormulaLocal)
   Next c
   Set UPS = Selection
End Function
```

In the Name Box:     UPS()   (use empty brackets, press Enter)
A range for conversion should be previously selected.